# Como manter o estado atual do GridView com Detail jQuery depois do Post Back

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

Estou usando a seguinte solução para minha grid: http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Build-Master-Detail-GridView-using-jQuery-in-ASPNet.aspx

Esta solução faz uma grid aparecer e desaperer conforme é clicado na imagem que causa o efeito (expand and collapse).

Ate ai tudo bem funciona perfeitamente igual o exemplo demo do site do aspsnippets, o problema foi quando adicionei em minhas colunas e na sub grid o evento para sorting que necessita chamar o método DataBind() para atualizar os dados na ordenação.

Depois que eu clico em uma coluna para ordenar ele faz o postback e fecha o expand ocutando novamente a sub grid.

Gostaria de saber se alguem sabe como posso manter o estado atual das grid depois do postback, exemplo quero que o que estavam abertos continuem abertos e o que esvam fechados continuem fechados.

Obs: A ordenação funciona normal, o único problema é que tem o incomodo de precisar abrir os expand de novo, já usei UpdatePanel e também não resolveu.

Obrigado.

Segue o codigo completo:
Aspx:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm001.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication0001.WebForm001" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $("[src*=plus]").live("click", function () {
        $(this).closest("tr").after("<tr><td></td><td colspan = '2'>" + $(this).next().html() + "</td></tr>")
        $(this).attr("src", "images/minus.png");
    });
    $("[src*=minus]").live("click", function () {
        $(this).attr("src", "images/plus.png");
        $(this).closest("tr").next().remove();
    });
</script>

<style>
    .Principal th {
        background-color: Gray;
    }

    .Detalhe {
        margin: 10px;
    }
</style>

</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager runat="server" />    
    <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:GridView ID="gvPrincipal" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" CssClass="Principal"
                DataKeyNames="Codigo" OnRowDataBound="gvPrincipal_RowDataBound"
                OnSorting="gvPrincipal_Sorting" AllowSorting="true">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="50">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <img alt="" style="cursor: pointer" src="plus" />
                            <asp:Panel ID="pnlDetalhe" runat="server" Style="display: none">
                                <asp:GridView ID="gvDetalhe" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" CssClass="Detalhe"
                                    OnSorting="gvDetalhe_Sorting" AllowSorting="true">
                                    <Columns>
                                        <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataField="Principal.Codigo" HeaderText="Principal.Codigo" />
                                        <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataField="Codigo" HeaderText="Codigo" SortExpression="Codigo" />
                                        <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataField="Descricao" HeaderText="Descricao" SortExpression="Descricao" />
                                    </Columns>
                                </asp:GridView>
                            </asp:Panel>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataField="Codigo" HeaderText="Codigo" SortExpression="Codigo" />
                    <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataField="Descricao" HeaderText="Descricao" SortExpression="Descricao" />
                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Segue o código completo do c#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace WebApplication0001
{
    public class Principal
    {
        public int Codigo { get; set; }
        public string Descricao { get; set; }
    }

    public class Detalhe
    {
        public int Codigo { get; set; }
        public string Descricao { get; set; }
        public Principal Principal { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class WebForm001 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        public static List<Principal> LstPrincipal;
        public static List<Detalhe> LstDetalhe;
        public static SortDirection SortDirecaoPrincipal;
        public static SortDirection SortDirecaoDetalhe;

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                PreenchePrincipal();
                PreencheDetalhe();

                gvPrincipal.DataSource = LstPrincipal;
                gvPrincipal.DataBind();
            }
        }

        private void PreenchePrincipal()
        {
            List<Principal> lstPrincipal = new List<Principal>()
            {
                new Principal(){ Codigo = 1, Descricao = "Principal 01"},
                new Principal(){ Codigo = 2, Descricao = "Principal 02"}              
            };

            LstPrincipal = new List<Principal>();
            LstPrincipal = lstPrincipal;               
        }

        private void PreencheDetalhe()
        {
            List<Detalhe> lstDetalhe = new List<Detalhe>()
            {
                new Detalhe(){ Codigo = 1, Descricao = "Detalhe 01", Principal = new Principal() { Codigo = 1}},
                new Detalhe(){ Codigo = 2, Descricao = "Detalhe 02", Principal = new Principal() { Codigo = 1}},
                new Detalhe(){ Codigo = 3, Descricao = "Detalhe 03", Principal = new Principal() { Codigo = 2}},
                new Detalhe(){ Codigo = 4, Descricao = "Detalhe 04", Principal = new Principal() { Codigo = 2}},
                new Detalhe(){ Codigo = 5, Descricao = "Detalhe 05", Principal = new Principal() { Codigo = 2}}
            };

            LstDetalhe = new List<Detalhe>();
            LstDetalhe = lstDetalhe;             
        }

        protected void gvPrincipal_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                int codigo = Convert.ToInt32(gvPrincipal.DataKeys[e.Row.RowIndex].Value);
                GridView gvDetalhe = e.Row.FindControl("gvDetalhe") as GridView;

                gvDetalhe.DataSource = LstDetalhe.Where(p => p.Principal.Codigo == codigo).ToList();
                gvDetalhe.DataBind();
            }
        }

        protected void gvPrincipal_Sorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.SortExpression == "Codigo")
            {
                if (SortDirecaoPrincipal == SortDirection.Ascending)
                {
                    SortDirecaoPrincipal = SortDirection.Descending;
                    gvPrincipal.DataSource = LstPrincipal.OrderBy(p => p.Codigo).ToList();
                    gvPrincipal.DataBind();
                }
                else
                {
                    SortDirecaoPrincipal = SortDirection.Ascending;
                    gvPrincipal.DataSource = LstPrincipal.OrderByDescending(p => p.Codigo).ToList();
                    gvPrincipal.DataBind();
                }             
            }
            else if (e.SortExpression == "Descricao")
            {
                if (SortDirecaoPrincipal == SortDirection.Ascending)
                {
                    SortDirecaoPrincipal = SortDirection.Descending;
                    gvPrincipal.DataSource = LstPrincipal.OrderBy(p => p.Descricao).ToList();
                    gvPrincipal.DataBind();
                }
                else
                {
                    SortDirecaoPrincipal = SortDirection.Ascending;
                    gvPrincipal.DataSource = LstPrincipal.OrderByDescending(p => p.Descricao).ToList();
                    gvPrincipal.DataBind();
                }
            }
        }

        protected void gvDetalhe_Sorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
        {
            GridView gvDetalhe = (GridView)sender;          

            int principalCodigo = Convert.ToInt32(gvDetalhe.Rows[0].Cells[0].Text);

            if (e.SortExpression == "Codigo")
            {
                if (SortDirecaoDetalhe == SortDirection.Ascending)
                {
                    SortDirecaoDetalhe = SortDirection.Descending;
                    gvDetalhe.DataSource = LstDetalhe.Where(p => p.Principal.Codigo == principalCodigo).ToList().OrderBy(p => p.Codigo).ToList();
                    gvDetalhe.DataBind();
                }
                else
                {
                    SortDirecaoDetalhe = SortDirection.Ascending;
                    gvDetalhe.DataSource = LstDetalhe.Where(p => p.Principal.Codigo == principalCodigo).ToList().OrderByDescending(p => p.Codigo).ToList();
                    gvDetalhe.DataBind();
                }
            }
            else if (e.SortExpression == "Descricao")
            {
                if (SortDirecaoDetalhe == SortDirection.Ascending)
                {
                    SortDirecaoDetalhe = SortDirection.Descending;
                    gvDetalhe.DataSource = LstDetalhe.Where(p => p.Principal.Codigo == principalCodigo).ToList().OrderBy(p => p.Descricao).ToList();
                    gvDetalhe.DataBind();
                }
                else
                {
                    SortDirecaoDetalhe = SortDirection.Ascending;
                    gvDetalhe.DataSource = LstDetalhe.Where(p => p.Principal.Codigo == principalCodigo).ToList().OrderByDescending(p => p.Descricao).ToList();
                    gvDetalhe.DataBind();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Poderia por favor postar o seu código aí? @Mauricio Ferraz

Comment: Sim , vou preparar o código somente o necessário e adiciono ele aqui no post

Comment: @PauloHDSousa segue o código completo, se poder ajudar eu agradeço. Abraço.